# Vertical CSS Carousel Fade the Background Elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, fade

I have this vertical CSS Carousel working fine.

```js
var carousel = $(".carousel"),
    currdeg  = 0;

$(".next").on("click", { d: "n" }, rotate);
$(".prev").on("click", { d: "p" }, rotate);

function rotate(e){
  if(e.data.d=="n"){
    currdeg = currdeg - 60;
  }
  if(e.data.d=="p"){
    currdeg = currdeg + 60;
  }
  carousel.css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotateX("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotateX("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "-o-transform": "rotateX("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "transform": "rotateX("+currdeg+"deg)"
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  padding: 70px 0;
  font: 15px/20px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.transformer {
  transform: translateY(150px);
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.carousel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.95;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.a {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #ed1c24;
}
.b {
  transform: rotateX(60deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #0072bc;
}
.c {
  transform: rotateX(120deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #39b54a;
}
.d {
  transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #f26522;
}
.e {
  transform: rotateX(240deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #630460;
} 
.f {
  transform: rotateX(300deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #8c6239;
}

.next, .prev {
  color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #999;
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s, top 0.1s;
}
.next:hover, .prev:hover { color: #000; }
.next:active, .prev:active {
  top: 104px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #999;
}
.next { right: 1em; }
.prev { left: 1em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="transformer">
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="item a">A</div>
    <div class="item b">B</div>
    <div class="item c">C</div>
    <div class="item d">D</div>
    <div class="item e">E</div>
    <div class="item f">F</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="next">Next</div>
<div class="prev">Prev</div>
  </div>
```

I'm just in need of help with some visual tweaking. 
How can I fade out the elements, so that only the div in view (front)
is 100% visible. The other elements should fade from 100% to 0%, depending
on how far away they are from the front.

Any ideas? Thank you very much.